# converting sql to linq (joins and group by)

Tags: linq

I am converting an old webforms app to asp.net mvc and I am having issues converting one of my sql statements into linq.  In particular, i need help with grouping and joins.  I have tried several ways by looking at various examples here and none have worked for me.

```
SELECT cp.PartNumber, cp.PartDescription, PFEP.PFEPTx, PFEP.KBQty, 
TX_QOH.QOH, TX_ReworkQOH.Rework_QOH as Rework, SUM(ShippingInput.Qty) AS 
'Ocean'
FROM CustomerParts as cp 

LEFT JOIN TX_QOH 
ON cp.PartNumber = TX_QOH.PN

LEFT JOIN TX_ReworkQOH 
ON cp.PartNumber = TX_ReworkQOH.PN

LEFT JOIN ShippingInput 
ON cp.PartNumber = ShippingInput.PN AND  ShippingInput.Status <> 'Received' 

LEFT JOIN PFEP
ON cp.PartNumber= PFEP.PN

WHERE cp.PartType = 'Actuator Part' AND cp.Division = 'Bayne' AND cp.Active 
= 'Yes' AND TX_QOH.QOH = '0'

Group By cp.PartNumber, TX_QOH.QOH, TX_ReworkQOH.Rework_QOH, 
cp.PartDescription, PFEP.PFEPTx, PFEP.KBQty
Order By cp.PartNumber ASC
```

Comment: format the code, maybe?

Comment: People are more likely to help fix an attempted translation than write the translation for you

Comment: *Don't* do that. That's a serious bug.  LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities is a query language for an ORM, not a replacement for SQL.You can't use LINQ without the ORM. Create proper entities with relations and navigation properties and let the ORM do its job of matching related rows and conveting them to objects

Comment: Another serious bug is using an ORM to perform reporting queries. Just *don't* use an ORM or LINQ for this. If you want to use EF, map the results of this view to an object instead of copying the entire query inside your web application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ Version

```
var queryNew = (from cp in db.MasterPartLists
            join tx in db.TxQohs on cp.CustomerPn equals tx.Pn into jTxQoh
            from tx in jTxQoh.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join c in db.ShipIns.Where(r => r.ShipInStatusId != 3) on cp.CustomerPn equals c.Pn into jShipIns
            from c in jShipIns.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join d in db.Pfeps on cp.CustomerPn equals d.CustomerPn into jPfeps
            from d in jPfeps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where d.PartTypeId == parttype && cp.CustomerDivisionId == division && cp.ActivePartId == 1 && tx.Qoh == 0
            group new {cp, d, tx, c} by new {cp.CustomerPn, tx.Qoh, cp.PartDescription, d.PfepTx, d.KbQty}
            into gcp
            orderby gcp.Key.CustomerPn
            select new
            {
                gcp.Key.CustomerPn,
                gcp.Key.PartDescription,
                gcp.Key.PfepTx,
                gcp.Key.KbQty,
                gcp.Key.Qoh,
                Ocean = (int?)gcp.Sum(r => r.c.Qty)
            });
```

SQL Version

```
var queryNew = "SELECT cp.CustomerPn, cp.PartDescription, Pfeps.PFEPTx, Pfeps.KBQty, TxQohs.Qoh, SUM(ShipIns.Qty) AS 'Ocean' "
                          + "FROM MasterPartLists as cp "
                          + "LEFT JOIN TxQohs "
                          + "ON cp.CustomerPn = TxQohs.Pn AND TxQohs.Qoh = '0' "
                          + "LEFT JOIN ShipIns "
                          + "ON cp.CustomerPn = ShipIns.Pn AND ShipIns.ShipStatusId <> '3' "
                          + "LEFT JOIN Pfep "
                          + "ON cp.CustomerPn = Pfeps.CustomerPn "
                          + "WHERE cp.PartTypeId = parttype AND cp.CustomerDivisionId = division AND cp.ActivePartId = '1' "
                          + "Group By cp.CustomerPn, TxQohs.Qoh, cp.PartDescription, Pfeps.PfepTx, Pfeps.KbQty "
                          + "Order By cp.CustomerPn ASC ";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously untested, and there may be null issues with trying to access fields when they may not exist due to the left join (e.g. SUM(ShippingInput.Qty)), which is why I moved some of the tests to lambda `Where` on the `join`

```
from cp in CustomerParts
join r_tx_qoh in TX_QOH.Where(r => r.QOH == "0") on cp.PartNumber equals r_tx_qoh.PN into j_tx_qoh
from r_tx_qoh in j_tx_qoh.DefaultIfEmpty()
join r_tx_reworkqoh in TX_ReworkQOH on cp.PartNumber equals r_tx_reworkqoh.PN into j_tx_reworkqoh
from r_tx_reworkqoh in j_tx_reworkqoh.DefaultIfEmpty()
join r_shippinginput in ShippingInput.Where(r => r.Status != "Received") on cp.PartNumber equals r_shippinginput.PN into j_shippinginput
from r_shippinginput in j_shippinginput.DefaultIfEmpty()
join r_pfep in PFEP on cp.PartNumber equals r_pfep.PN into j_pfep
from r_pfep in j_pfep.DefaultIfEmpty()
where cp.PartType == "Actuator Part" && cp.Division == "Bayne" && cp.Active == "Yes"
group new { cp, r_pfep, r_tx_qoh, r_tx_reworkqoh, r_shippinginput } by new { cp.PartNumber, r_tx_qoh.QOH, r_tx_reworkqoh.Rework_QOH, cp.PartDescription, r_pfep.PFEPTx, r_pfep.KBQty } into gcp
orderby gcp.Key.PartNumber
select new { gcp.Key.PartNumber, gcp.Key.PartDescription, gcp.Key.PFEPTx, gcp.Key.KBQty, tcp.Key.QOH, Rework = gcp.Key.Rework_QOH, Ocean = gcp.Sum(r => r.r_shippinginput.Qty) }
```

Comment: Thanks NetMage.  This got me very close.  Please find working linq equivalents below.